# How would I separate this class?

Tags: c++, oop, opengl

I'm learning computer graphics and OpenGL, and I load models from my own binary format with a JSON manifest file to keep track of the assets.

The `Model` class I have right now keeps track of the OpenGL objects necessary to draw it with, as well as handling the processing of the 3D model files:

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model(const std::string &filename);
    // read the manifest
    // load the appropriate binary files
    // finally make the OpenGL objects this class keeps track of

    // ... etc, like draw()
private:
    // handles for various OpenGL objects
}
```

I would like to separate the file processing from the bookkeeping of OpenGL graphics stuff as I feel like that's too much responsibility for a single class. How would I go about doing that?

I thought about making a `ModelLoader` class, but I don't think there's any state that needs keeping track of in order to load this. So maybe I should make it a function inside a `ModelLoader` namespace. I played around with it but ended up with:

```
// ModelLoader.hpp
#include "Model.hpp"

namespace ModelLoader
{
    Model load(const std::string &filename);
}
```

---

```
// ModelLoader.cpp
#include "ModelLoader.hpp"

Model ModelLoader::load()
{
    return Model();
}
```

---

```
// Model.hpp
class Model;

namespace ModelLoader
{
    Model load();
};

class Model
{
    friend Model ModelLoader::load();
public:
    // ... etc, like draw()
private:
    Model(const std::string &filename); // accessible only through ModelLoader::load()
    // handles for various OpenGL objects
}
```

There was a circular dependency between `Model` and `ModelLoader`, and what I have up there was the only way I could get it to compile. But as you can see, that kind of defeats the purpose of the declarations inside `ModelLoader.hpp`, plus it's duplicated code. I'm still not too good with C++ and object oriented design. Should I just go with what I had before? If I really wanted to separate file loading from bookkeeping, how should I do it? What's wrong with my attempts?

Comment: What's the point of `load` if it just passes the filename to `Model`'s constructor anyway?

Comment: @immibis No, load is supposed to read the manifest, load the corresponding binary files, and buffer them. That way, `Model` only keeps track of the OpenGL objects

Comment: But with your design here, `Model::Model` (the constructor) is what does the reading.

Comment: @immibis That's what I started off with. Everything was shoved into `Model`'s constructor. File loading, buffering, and finally the real constructing. I wanted to move the file loading and buffering out of the class

Comment: My idea was to make a private default constructor, make `ModelLoader::load()` a friend, and have that do the stuff. I'll probably just implement serialization as Keith suggested. If what I have is a horrible design, yeah I agree. Sometimes I get too excited about seeing results of new things I learn, so I hack stuff together. Plus, most of my experience was with Java, so I have trouble thinking in C++. Not to mention I'm still fairly new to OOD.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a slightly different approach.  Make your class know how to serialize and deserialize itself from a stream.

That way you can use string streams, file streams, network streams, etc.